# Utilizing a slider and an action button in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

This is the code that I currently have typed up:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"), 
  p(),
  actionButton("Date", "BLUFOR", "OPFOR"),
  
  sliderInput("integer", "Integer:",
             min = 3, max = 18,
             value = 10,),
  icon(),
  tableOutput("values")
)
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error in validateIcon(icon) : 
  Invalid icon. Use Shiny's 'icon()' function to generate a valid icon.
```

Comment: Remove `icon(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to `actionButton()` is `icon` which is used to display an icon on button. `"OPFOR"` is not a valid value for it hence you get the error. Try :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"), 
  p(),
  actionButton("Date", "BLUFOR"),
  
  sliderInput("integer", "Integer:",
              min = 3, max = 18,
              value = 10),
  tableOutput("values")
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]